# True lost luggage - airline haggle over compensation

Tags: airlines, compensation, lost-luggage

Few months ago, Air Botswana lost one of my luggage pieces. I have followed their terms, allowed 21 days to search for it, submitted the forms with details and list of items. They took their time looking for the luggage, and two months later they give me a call, saying that they are willing to pay for half the amount that I have requested in my claim, since I have not submitted receipts.

Just to add to this mess, I have payed for direct flight, they couldn't provide it, so I go a very long connection for the same price, and that is probably the reason they lost my luggage.

Now, I am really not interested of searching receipts for each and every item.

Is this normal for airlines to haggle? 
Should I haggle with them or accept the offer?

Comment: Can you threaten them with legal action in the Botswanan courts and see what happens?

Comment: I can, the question, is it worth it? They give me something...

Comment: They usually ask for receipts; especially if you are claiming close to the maximum allowed; but if they are offering half, I would at least respond with a counter-offer, saying you cannot locate all the receipts, but would they pay 75% instead of 50%.

Comment: Do you have travel insurance? Some credit cards do include it, and you may possibly get a better deal, and/or they may be better at negotiating with the airline.

Comment: Yes. It could be a good option. I have checked there, but I must finalize with the airline first, that's one of their conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, an anecdotal example: in hundreds of flights, I had one luggage loss (with Delta), and they paid what I asked for, without any discussion.

It probably depends a lot on the airline and the country. But I would *not* think it is normal for the airline to haggle, unless your claims seem exorbitant.